# stop loading script on some pages only

Tags: jquery

I'm using getScript to fire a script when jquery has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.getScript("js/hscroll.js");
});
```

And when a project is complete I can create other functions with:

```
$(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", function(e, pid){ 
    // turn off script
});
```

How can I turn off hscroll.js script when a project has loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669065/unload-files-loaded-with-getscript

Comment: So this is not possible / shouldn't but done. I want to remove the effects of this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hsrcoll.js code is [this one](http://paulicio.us/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/hscroll.js), then it has initialization code like this:

```
/* Initialization code. */
if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
```

That means you can deinstall it with this:

```
/* Unhook code. */
if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
}
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null;
```

If this isn't your hscroll.js, then please post a reference to the one you're using so we can look at it.

Comment: I forgot to give my thanks, I didn't see the initialization code, I wouldn't know the correct way to unhook anyway. Thank you very much.