# RequireJS: How do I unload previously loaded javascript file? Aka Exclusive Dependancies? Or maybe Reset RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

I have 2 javascript files that cannot co-exist. 
If a user click on one button, it loads one js file. 
If a user clicks another button, it loads the other file. But the last one needs to be *unloaded* first

Here is generally what I have:

```
//pseudocode
if user clicks button one
    loadScript(one);
if user clicks button two
    loadScript(two);

//not psuedocode
function loadScript(name)
{
      var javascriptLoc = name + "/config.js";

      //Unload any scripts that were previously loaded by requirejs
      require.undef(); //HELP

      //once config.js is loaded by requirejs...
      require([javascriptLoc], function(util) {

          //do stuff

      });
}
```

Is there a way to unload one/config.js and load two/config.js *instead*? Then when a user clicks on "one", it would load one/config.js *instead of* two/config.js?

Other ways to word the question:

- what do I do in requirejs when I have **exclusive dependancies**...
- how do I deal with **conflict resolution** in requirejs...
- how do I **reset or unload** scripts previously loaded by requirejs...

Comment: ...Am I going to have to use some other method besides RequireJS? :( http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/for-your-script-loading-needs/

Comment: Other script loaders can't unload scripts either. :(

Comment: Focus on getting these script files to co-exist.  There are all sorts of ways to sandbox a script file's contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, browsers don't let you unload JavaScript files. If you load a file a.js that says:

```
var a = 345;
```

There is no command in JS/HTML that can undo that. (See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669065/unload-files-loaded-with-getscript/4669114#4669114), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591685/how-can-i-dynamically-unload-a-javascript-file))

You can load a new set of JS commands that negates the effect of the first file, for example:

```
if (typeof a === "undefined") 
   var a = 34;
else
   a = 34;
```

This is starting to get complicated though, isn't it? It might be easier to redesign the modules so reloading isn't necessary, for example:

```
function option1() {
}
function option2() {
}

//if user clicks button 1
currentOption = option1();
//if user clicks button 2
currentOption = option2();
```

Comment: Doesn't removing the actual script tag unload the related script file?